# Transferring Australian superannuation to United Kingdom (for Australian citizen)

Tags: united-kingdom, australia, pension

I am an Australian citizen now permanently resident in the UK, while I lived and worked in Australia my employers contributed to my superannuation fund.

A) Is it possible to transfer my superannuation to a UK Pension fund?

B) How to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Only temporary residents can access their super when leaving Australia permanently. That includes transferring the benefit out of an Australian super fund. Australian citizens and Australian permanent residents cannot access their superannuation because they can always chose to retire in Australia.

A recent rule that allows an exception is the [Trans-Tasman retirement savings portability scheme for individuals](https://www.ato.gov.au/Individuals/Super/In-detail/Transferring/Trans-Tasman-retirement-savings-portability-scheme-for-individuals/).

> From 1 July 2013, individuals may transfer retirement savings between Australia and New Zealand after their emigration from one country to the other.

[This QA](http://www.superguide.com.au/accessing-superannuation/accessing-super-early/permanent-departure-from-australia) covers the issue of accessing super early.

There are special conditions for individuals who are over the preservation age that are living overseas, who can cash out super under some circumstances.

Comment: That is a good link for releasing super early.  Would it be possible to transfer to a non-australian pension fund rather than releasing the super?

Comment: @AndrewBickerton it's the same rule. There's a recent exception for NZ only. I updated the answer.